# JSP Page taking too long to load

Tags: performance, jsp

I have a JSP Page (this is a tabbed view) with 2 text boxes, 2 dropdowns, checkbox & 4 list boxes.

One dropdown is populated by making connection to db and query through prepared statement.

The 4 listboxes & 2nd dropdown get populated through AJAX if the checkbox is checked. By default the checkbox is unchecked.

The problem here is, the JSP Page takes too long to load. It is approx 0.11 min to load the page. 
Even before I check the checkbox and populate the list boxes and the 2nd dropdown, the page loads too slow.

Does being page in tab slow the performance?

Any idea why is this happening and what can I do to improve the page performance?

Comment: Here is an update. I have checked that the issue is with the query. So to avoid this, I am loading the page first, then trying to make AJAX call to populate the dropdown. But I would like to know without clicking how can I populate the dropdown using AJAX Call? I am doing document.load=fun(); and in fun() I am calling the Ajax function which populates the dropdown. But this however is not working unless user clicks on the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaroud for this issue. I am loading the page first and then making AJAX call to load just this dropdowndown control. In that way, user won't feel that the page  is loading slowly. I know this is not a permanent solution.